# Site Owner Checklist for Site Collection Migration to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: site-collection, team-sites, content-migration

My company is getting ready for a migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. I am tasked with getting a checklist for Site Owners so they can prepare their team sites for migration to the new 2013 platform. Does anyone have a "go to" site or link that details the necessary/important steps a Site Owner has to take for migration of Team Sites to SharePoint 2013? I found some but just wanted to know what notes some of you guys had.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps as that I followed when I did migration lastly,

Steps to perform simple migration with DB attach approach

1. Get backup of MOSS content db from VS 2005/08
2. Create blank web app at SP 2010 new environment
3. Detach content db from newly created web application
4. Restore the backup db at SQL server 2008 r2 at new environment
5. Attach the restored database to the newly created web application
6. Test Restored content DB to identify the customization which is not installed on new web app
7. Run Visual upgrade command

Actual Command:
1. Open SQL server management studio at MOSS environment. Run following SQL query to get 
backup of the content DB

BACKUP DATABASE WSS_Content
TO DISK = 'E:\DBBackup\WSS_Content.bak'

2. Create web application from central admin at new environment.
3. Open power shell command. Run following command to detach the existing content db from 
   newly created web application.

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Dismount-SPContentDatabase WSS_New_DB

4. Open SQL server management studio at new environment. Run following SQL query to restore 
   the backup database.

RESTORE DATABASE BD_portal
FROM DISK='\ps7568\BD_Portal_Back_Up\BDPORAddTAL.bak'
WITH REPLACE,
MOVE 'WSS_Content_BDPortal' TO 'D:\BD portal DB\BD_Portal.mdf',
MOVE 'WSS_Content_BDPortal_log' TO 'D:\BD portal DB\BD_Portal_log.ldf'

5. Attach the restored database to newly created web application. Run following PowerShell 
   command. You will get upgrade log report also. (Check out below snap running the command)

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Mount-SPContentDatabase "WSS_New_DB" -DatabaseServer "V-COLLAB3-NEW\SHAREPOINT" -
WebApplication http://v-collab3-new:1234/

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Mount-SPContentDatabase "WSS_New_DB" -DatabaseServer "V-COLLAB3-
NEW\SHAREPOINT" -WebApplication http://v-collab3-new:1234/
100.00%

Mount-SPContentDatabase: Upgrade completed with errors.
Review the upgrade log file located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server 
Extensions\14\LOGS\Upgrade-20110731-231748-447.log.
The number of errors and warnings is listed at the end of the upgrade log file.

6. Tests a content database. Run following PowerShell command to test the newly attached 
   content database. This command will help to identify what features and components are 
   referred in content database but not installed on web application.

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Test-SPContentDatabase -name WSS_New_DB -webapplication http://v-collab3-new:1234/

7. Visual upgrade all the sites under new web application. Run following powershell command.
   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
   $site = Get-SPSite http://v-collab3-new:1234/
   $site.VisualUpgradeWebs()
8. You must use Credential Security Provider (CredSSP) authentication. This authentication mechanism, introduced with Windows Vista, allows an application to delegate the credentials from one machine to another, a process called double hopping. This will enable you to provide the credentials that allow the SharePoint PowerShell cmdlets to talk to the Microsoft SQL Server that is hosting your SharePoint databases. If you do not use CredSSP and you try to remotely execute a SharePoint cmdlet, you are likely to receive a message that indicates the farm is unavailable. In the output from the Winrm get winrm/config/service command shown previously, notice that CredSSP is equal to False. There are several ways you can modify WinRM configuration options, including Group Policy, login scripts, and the command prompt. To enable CredSSP authentication though command-line interfaces, complete the following tasks.

a. On the computer from which you are remoting, such as your Windows 7 desktop, type the following command, where Web1 is the SharePoint server. Type Y when prompted to confirm that you want to enable CredSSP authentication.
Enable-WSManCredSSP -role client -DelegateComputer Web1

b. On the SharePoint server where you are remoting to, type
Enable-WSManCredSSP -role server

2. Query changed given as below,

   use master

   RESTORE DATABASE WSS_Content_2010
   FROM DISK='C:\Restore Backup 15-10-2014\ITConnect\ContentDBBackup\WSS_Content_2010.BAK'
   WITH REPLACE,
   MOVE 'WSS_Content_2010' TO 'C:\Restore Backup 15-10-
   2014\ITConnect\ContentDBBackup\WSS_Content_2010.mdf',
   MOVE 'WSS_Content_2010_log' TO 'C:\Restore Backup 15-10-
   2014\ITConnect\ContentDBBackup\WSS_Content_2010_log.ldf'
   GO

   use master

   RESTORE DATABASE WSS_Content_1971
   FROM DISK='C:\Restore Backup 15-10-
   2014\ITConnect\ContentDBBackup\WSS_Content_2010_ITCONNECT.BAK'
   WITH 
   MOVE 'WSS_Content_1971' TO 'C:\Restore Backup 15-10-
   2014\ITConnect\ContentDBBackup\WSS_Content_2010.mdf',
   MOVE 'WSS_Content_1971_log' TO 'C:\Restore Backup 15-10-
   2014\ITConnect\ContentDBBackup\WSS_Content_2010_log.ldf'